# How do I add MovieClips to the stage while using AIR?

Tags: actionscript-3, air, movieclip, addchild

So I had been messing around in AS3 for awhile and had done some basic starting flash game things, but then found out I could use air to make them for mobile platforms.  So I tried copying over what I had worked on before, but I am running into issues.

Right now I am just trying to find out how to add an instance of a MovieClip to the stage. I have an image converted to a MovieClip with it's own class so I can manipulate it later (such as moving around) and I have this in my Main class:

```
class Main extends MovieClip
{
    var space:Background;  //Background is the MovieClip

    function Main():void
    {
        space = new Background(stage);
        stage.addChild(space);
    }
}
```

But when I run the program, the image doesn't show up.  It works that way when I just had a standard AS3 program and I don't understand why it would be different when I am trying to use AIR.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Is your Main class is `Document` class?

Comment: That was the issue!  I can't believe I missed it.  The Document class section was blank this whole time.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rajneesh Gaikwad had the answer, I didn't have my Main class as my Document class.

Answer (score 1):

Put the word 'public' in front of 'class' in your first line.

Also remove the 'stage' from the first line in your constructor: make it `space = new Background();`

And do you really need 'stage' in the addChild statement?  Unnecessarily verbose!

Comment: -Adding public in front of class doesn't change anything in relation to the image not showing up, I made my Background class take in stage to use it as a reference for things later in the program, and no, I guess I don't really need stage in front of the addChild statement

Answer (score 1):

I can run this code through the AIR compiler (AIR SDK 3.8 or later):

```
package  

{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class MAIN extends MovieClip
    {
        var space:Background; 

        public function MAIN()
        {

            space = new Background();
            stage.addChild(space);
        }
    }

}
```

With an image inside the Background class it shows up fine. My 'Background' is a library symbol linked for Actionscript. If your 'Background' is pure Actionscript are you adding a graphic to *it*?

Comment: I also have my 'Background' as a symbol in my library linked for Actionscript.  I have the image I want to use in my library that I converted to the symbol.  And I just copied your code for main to test it and it still doesn't work for me.

Comment: Can you show me what you have in your Background class?

Comment: It's just a brown square. Nothing special! Make sure your .x and .y put your graphic in a viewable place on stage. Is your Background an AS class or a library symbol with AS linkage?